# Getting a list of events with data in Web3py

Tags: events, ethereum, web3py

I have a working code, but periodically after receiving data, the terminal gives an error:
UserWarning: The log with transaction hash: HexBytes('0xa5dadecd01e175d70caaa7fb8e872bb68b45601fd714294b2c1368b8cff077d8') and logIndex: 73 encountered the following error during processing: MismatchedABI(The event signature did not match the provided ABI). It has been discarded.
warnings.warn(
Next, data appears, and then (), after again a series of receiving normal data. How can you get rid of this?
I'm using the latest proxy contract ABI 0x84db6eE82b7Cf3b47E8F19270abdE5718B936670.

I would also like to extract data from each event: staker, time and amount in 'ether' and try to solve the problem of filtering with a limit of 10000 blocks, a loop may be needed, since I want to get a list of all events from the block on which the contract was deployed

```
# import the following dependencies
import json
from web3 import Web3
from web3.auto import w3
import time


# add your blockchain connection information
#connect to infura eth chain http end point
infura_url='https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/e212e98e02a74730a1c6382e7ae6f95d'

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

#connection status
w3.isConnected()

# ankr pool address and abi
ankr_pool = '0x84db6eE82b7Cf3b47E8F19270abdE5718B936670'
```

```
ankr_pool_abi = json.loads('[ABI this contract 0xD201a7dF1D0F7E066EFdD448CBc8433F0b88C3e9]')
```

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=ankr_pool, abi=ankr_pool_abi)

greeting_Event = contract.events.StakeConfirmed() # Modification

def handle_event(event):
    receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(event['transactionHash'])
    result = greeting_Event.processReceipt(receipt) # Modification
    print(result)

def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_all_entries():
            handle_event(event)
            time.sleep(poll_interval)

block_filter = w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 16128812 , 'address': ankr_pool})
log_loop(block_filter, 2)
```

`

I tried to use the log log, but I ran into data decoding problems, I believe that using the filter by events is still easier

Comment: This question is multiple problems at once and does not have a repeatable example. Can you please try to edit your question and narrow it down to the actual problem with repeatable full code to understand what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: If the aim is to get all the events easily, then using some 3rd party packages like Morlais will be much more helpful rather than using web3.py. If that is a solution you are interested in I can get show you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The MismatchedABI warning might be coming because you made some changes to the function after deploying the contract and are using the ABI of the contract with your changes unknowingly. It's good to double check that.
Although such warnings are harmless and can be disabled by using the `warnings` library:

```
import warnings

def my_function():
    # silence harmless warnings
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

For getting the event logs, you could try the following:

```
import Web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(RPC_URL))

while from_block < target_block:
  contract = w3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(CONTRACT_ADDRESS), abi=ABI)
  functionEvents = contract.events.MyEvent.getLogs(fromBlock=from_block, toBlock=toBlock)

  # < Your desired logic >

from_block = from_block + 10000 + 1
```

You could then use the following code inside your while loop to decode event logs:

```
txHash = myEvent.transactionHash.hex()
txInputReceipt = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(txHash)
logs = contract.events.MyEvent().processReceipt(txInputReceipt)
```

Or just use: `txInputReceipt.logs`.

This is just the pseudocode, hope you get the idea.
Checkout this Web3Py doc for more helpful functions on this: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/v5/contracts.html?highlight=processreceipt#web3.contract.ContractEvents